# Activity ActionBar can't showing the launcher icon and drawer layout icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I want a light theme with action bar icon, drawer layout icon and action bar text. I used `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in my `style.xml` file as below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

It shows the required result on my mobile but It shows only action bar title and does not show action bar icon and drawer layout icon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXBKD.png

But when I change the theme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

I get the following errors.

```
06-09 12:46:32.111  27494-27494/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xperts.net.pk.navwithbaseactivity, PID: 27494
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xperts.net.pk.navwithbaseactivity/xperts.net.pk.navwithbaseactivity.FirstActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:122)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
            at xperts.net.pk.navwithbaseactivity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:37)
            at xperts.net.pk.navwithbaseactivity.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navwithbaseactivity"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.0'
}
```

Below is my `BaseActivity.java` Code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/*deprecation*/
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity { //ActionBarActivity
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);

        // if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // // on first time display view for first nav item
        // // displayView(0);
        // }
    }

    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items
        if (navMenuIcons == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i]));
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i],
                        navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
            }
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
        // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            finish();// finishes the current activity
            break;
        // case 2:
        // Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, third.class);
        // startActivity(intent2);
        // finish();
        // break;
        // case 3:
        // Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, fourth.class);
        // startActivity(intent3);
        // finish();
        // break;
        // case 4:
        // Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, fifth.class);
        // startActivity(intent4);
        // finish();
        // break;
        // case 5:
        // Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, sixth.class);
        // startActivity(intent5);
        // finish();
        // break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Please guide me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

remove style.xml file from all values folder and rename ActionBarActivity to Activity and solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

this is because new app-compat with Material. new guidelines prevent from showing icon, you can bring it back only by disabling showing title and using `setCustomView` for add custom layout with icon and `TextView` to your `ActionBar`